# addEventListener - v0

Tags: javascript

The facade pattern is used to abstract adding events.  Should support IE5+ as stands.

Looking for minor improvements.  Don't need to support prior to IE5.

I choose not to use a library.

```
/*addEL
**  dependencies - none 
**  browser - IE5+
**  notes - improved per answer
*/
NS.addEL = (function binding() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        return function addEventListener(element, type, callNow) {
            element.addEventListener(type, callNow);
        };
    }
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        return function attachEvent(element, type, callNow) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, callNow);
        };
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

- Why does binding have parameters? The closure isn't passing any.
- As far as I know, 75% of browsers (including IE9+) actually support `addEventListener`. If you check for `attachEvent` first, you are wasting that 75% assurance. Instead, check for `addEventListener` first and 75% of the time, your code is evaluating just one condition.
- For better readability, use common conventions when naming. Element references can be shortened to `el`, events are usually `ev` (because `e` sometimes refer to error objects), and event handlers are usually called `handler` or `callback`.
- Although you might say that you are not going to support older/other browsers, that does not mean you should recklessly code.

  In your code, if you used `attachEvent` was not supported, you use `addEventListener`. But what if the browser hasn't got `addEventListener` either? The binding will crash trying to use it since `addEventListener` a last resort that is, in this case, not supported.

  So I added a third case which makes `NS.addEL` be a function that does nothing if both methods are not available.

And so:

```
NS.addEL = (function binding(){

  if(window.addEventListener){
    return function addEventListener(el, ev, handler){
      el.addEventListener(ev, handler);
    }
  }

  if(window.attachEvent) {
    return function attachEvent(el, ev, handler){
      el.attachEvent('on' + ev, handler);
    }
  }

  return function(){/*not supported for some reason*/}

}());
```

Another approach to this is the following code. It's shorter, but performs checks everytime the function is called. If the browser supports neither, then nothing is actually executed:

```
NS.addEL = function addEL(el,ev,handler){
  if(window.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(ev,handler);
  } else if(window.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('on' + ev,handler);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have to disagree about unnecessarily abbreviating variable names. Longer variable names are always better.

Comment: @pure_code well, in your code `type` could mean anything. It could mean type of a value  (as in `typeof`) or something else. Also, when i first read the code, I had to decipher what `callNow` was and after reading further into the code, it was the event handler.

Comment: Is there any reason you're naming the functions you're returning? Returning anonymous functions works just fine and regardless they'll be called as `NS.addEL`

Comment: @Joseph in your code, you don't need the `else if`, just `if`, as there is a return in the preceding `if`.

Comment: @Joseph - your second snippet is less efficient as it runs a check multiple times; however that check only needs to be run once.

Comment: @pure_code Yes, I did say it performs checks everytime. But it's shorter.